# Images uploaded from mobile have incorrect orientation

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm developing Ruby on Rails app with Carrierwave Gem. Inside the app, user can upload profile image. It works well on desktop, but when you upload the image from mobile device, the image is shown sideway.

So my questions are :

1) What is the proper way to correct the orientation?

2) Is it possible to correct the orientation with Carrierwave?

Answer (score 2):

before you do the upload set auto_orient
how about if you set the carrier wave as follow

create / add app/uploaders/image_uploader.rb add this code below

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  process :fix_exif_rotation
  def fix_exif_rotation
      manipulate! do |image|
        image.tap(&:auto_orient)
      end
  end
end
```